# Search Bar AutoComplete by Address and Place Name - Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

## Goal

I want to make my search box auto-complete detecting place name and address.

Currently, my search box auto-complete detecting only the address.

I used this one in my iOS app. Result is looking good for addresses but not place name.

```
https://github.com/shmidt/GooglePlacesSearchController
```

[image]

I want it to detect places, like `B&H Photo` in NYC and so on ?

Example what I'm trying to do

[image]

Is it a paid service that I need to enable on Google API Console Library ?

Can someone sheds some lights on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Just change your `GooglePlacesSearchController` initialization parameter `placeType` to `.noFilter`

```
let controller = GooglePlacesSearchController(
    delegate: self, apiKey: GoogleMapsAPIServerKey, placeType: .noFilter)
```

For anyone with the same question but different [implementation](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/autocomplete) , just add a filter to your `GMSAutocompleteViewController`

```
let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
autocompleteController.delegate = self

// Specify a filter.
let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
filter.type = .noFilter
autocompleteController.autocompleteFilter = filter
```